# Android : set position text in custom shape?

Tags: android, textview, shapes

I have a custom `Shape` that i add in this `Shape` some text . But i can't change `position` of text in this `shape`.My app is chat mobile .

[image]

This is my `shape.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle"> 
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>    

    <stroke android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#ff000000"/>

    <padding android:left="1dp"
             android:top="1dp"
             android:right="1dp"
             android:bottom="1dp"/> 

    <corners android:radius="30dp"/> 
</shape>
```

This is my `xml` but i add my `TextViews` programmatically :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtInpuConversation"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:hint="@string/edt_Conversation" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSend"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/btn_Conversation" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I add my `Shape` with :

```
txt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.testo);
```

Comment: where is are you using the shape.xml?

Comment: is this shape background of your TextView or a seperate View? Your Layout XML is not helpful for that. You can post your class which your shape and textview are created.

Comment: txt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.testo);

Comment: My code is huge .my friend.

Comment: just increase the padding

Comment: did you try to increase left padding?

Comment: ;) ok. good work . please insert this answer and i will checked that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should increase padding.

```
<padding android:left="1dp" <<<
         android:top="1dp"
         android:right="1dp"
         android:bottom="1dp"/>
```

Or:

```
txtviewUser.setPadding(20, 0, 20, 0);
```